# How can I determine if an SQL result has been returned in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, db2, conditional-statements, ibm-midrange

I am trying to condition a table so that it only shows when SQL results are returned. If no values are returned, then do not display the table. Here is what I have:

```
## PPAP Information
$q23 = "SELECT * FROM $modlible.P0353 JOIN $amflible.CUSMAS ON PCUSNO = CUSNO WHERE PITEM='$id'";
$stmt23 = db2_prepare($con, $q23);
$result23 = db2_execute($stmt23);
$fin23 = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt23);
```

How can I detect whether or not a result has been returned to me?

Comment: Check results on NULL value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
$iRows = db2_num_rows($stmt23);
if ($iRows > 0) {
   //Do if zero results
} else {
   //Do if more results
}
```

or you can check

```
if ($fin23) {
    //Row was fetched
}
```

Comment: Great idea. Can't get it to work though. I did a var_dump on $iRows and get int(-1) in both cases. It doesn't make sense though because that number should change if a result is returned.

Comment: if (!$fin23) {
    //Blank
    } else {
    //Result is returned

Answer (score 0):

You can check the SQL code returned. If the code is SQL0100 (+100) it means no rows were returned.

Comment: With this, I get an error in my PHP log file. I'd rather do something else because I use that log alot and its hard when you have a bunch of unnecessary errors.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no results your while loop will not loop

```
while($fin23 = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt23)){
    // print your results
}
```

Comment: With this, I get an error in my PHP log file. I'd rather do something else because I use that log alot and its hard when you have a bunch of unnecessary errors.